# How to use an accelerator table in a modal dialog box?

Tags: winapi

I'm programming with the Win32 API, not MFC.

Comment: See new edit. You do realize with the information provided it's kind of a guessing game. :-)

Comment: I'll have a menu inside the dialog, and want to use accelerator keys for the menu.

Comment: Well then do what I said with the ampersand in the freakin' menu resource.

Comment: The simplest way is to use the dialog box modelessly. Then you can add a call to TranslateAccelerator. Otherwise you can install a message filter.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `DialogBox` API does not have accelerators to translate, and it has to be done on the message loop prior to dispatching messages.

This problem can be solved in the following way:

- use `SetWindowsHookEx` API to install thread hook of [`WH_GETMESSAGE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644981%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) type - this enables you to see messages before they are returned to `DialogBox`'s message loop
- on the hook procedure, filter messages of interest out (`PM_REMOVE`, then `WM_KEYFIRST`..`WM_LAST` message, then window is of your interest as well)
- route the message to [`TranslateAccelerator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646373%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and in case of success, invalidate it by updating `MSG.mesasge` with `WM_NULL` to "remove" it from API message loop

#### 24 May 2014 Update

User [Mick P.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2946737/mick-p) added a code snippet that follows instructions above (for some reason this was rejected by peer review here, but it's worth posting) and they worked well for him. Here is the code (some things are questionable but it's better than nothing for those needing a quick start):

```
static HWND g_hDialog = NULL;
static HHOOK g_hHook = NULL;

static LRESULT CALLBACK HookProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    LRESULT nResult = 1;
    if(nCode == HC_ACTION && wParam == PM_REMOVE)
    {
        MSG *p = (MSG*) lParam;
        if(p->message >= WM_KEYFIRST && p->message <= WM_KEYLAST)     
            if(g_hDialog == GetForegroundWindow())
            {
                HWND gf = GetFocus(); // ignore if edit-able control
                if(DLGC_HASSETSEL & ~SendMessage(gf, WM_GETDLGCODE, 0, 0)
                  || ES_READONLY & GetWindowLong(gf, GWL_STYLE)) 
                {
                    static HACCEL ha = // leaky
                        LoadAccelerators(..., MAKEINTRESOURCEW(IDR_MYACCEL));
                    if(TranslateAcceleratorW(g_hDialog, ha, p))
                    {
                        p->message = WM_NULL;
                        nResult = 0; 
                    }
                }
            }
    }
    if(nCode < 0 || nResult)
        return CallNextHookEx(g_hHook,nCode,wParam,lParam);
    return nResult;
}

static INT_PTR CALLBACK DialogProc(HWND hWnd, UINT Msg, 
  WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(Msg)
    {
    case WM_INITDIALOG:
        g_hHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_GETMESSAGE, HookProc, ...,  GetCurrentThreadId());
        g_hDialog = hWnd;
        return 1;
    case WM_NCDESTROY:
        UnhookWindowsHookEx(g_hHook);
        break;
    }                                                                      
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you have the TranslateMessage(...) function in your message pump. If so, accelerator keys should work. Realize a modal dialog freezes all other windows in your app until it is dismissed.

```
BOOL bRet;
while( (bRet = GetMessage( &msg, hWnd, 0, 0 )) != 0)
{ 
    if( bRet == -1 )
    {
        // handle the error and possibly exit
    }
    else
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg); //<< make sure this is present
        DispatchMessage(&msg); 
    }
}
```

Be sure and put an ampersand in front of your controls caption to "activate" the acceleration. Example: &OK or &Cancel. A small underline should now show up under the first letter indicating it worked. And that letter becomes the acceleration key. It does not have to be the first letter. E&xit. Line shows up under the "x" and that is the acceleration key.

Comment: I repeat my question : How to use an accelerator table in a MODAL DIALOG BOX ? You don't have access to the message loop used in a modal dialog box !!!

Answer (score -1):

Look at this example http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646337.aspx#editable_acc. Probably it's what are you looking for.

Comment: There must be something similar to this article
"How to use accelerator keys and a main menu on the dialog box in
Visual C++"
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/100770/en-gb
but using the Win32 API, instead of MFC.

Comment: The answer is right there in the article you linked to in your comment. I suggest you stand-back a bit and re-think what you're doing. It happens to all of us, because you can't "see" the answer right now.